# Is it possible to append a stdout to another stdout?

Tags: shell, unix, append, tail

I'm trying to run a command like:

```
gunzip -dc file.gz | tail +5c
```

So this will output the **binary** file contents minus the first 4 bytes to stdout, and it works. Now I need to append 3 extra bytes to the end of the stream, but only using stdout, never a file.

Imagine the file contains:

```
1234567890
```

With the current command, I get:

```
567890
```

But I need:

```
567890000
```

So... any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so based on the answers, the final solution was:

```
gzcat file.gz | tail -c +5 | echo 000
```

I didn't need to, and actually shouldn't, use the `tr -d '\n'`, as it will remove the newlines in the middle of the file.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
{ gunzip -dc file.gz | tail -c 5 | tr -d '\n'; echo 000; }
```

Comment: Why remove newlines at all? I imagine it would only be necessary if `tail` introduced a trailing newline, which it does not.

Comment: The file is binary, so I'm not sure if replacing newlines is a good idea. The objective is to keep the original output as is and then just add the three extra bytes at the end.

Answer (score -1):

May something like

$ echo "`gunzip -dc file.gz | tail +5c`BBB"

(where BBB are your three extra bytes) work for you?

Comment: Hi @Fredrik, I understand it looks inappropriate, but I'm new to stackoverflow and couldn't figure out quickly how to escape the "`" characters.

Comment: I don't think the tail command accepts extra parameters like 'BBB'. At least in HP-UX.

Comment: BBB is not a tail parameter. Please notice the couple of `` . BBB is just the trailing part of the echo parameter.

Comment: Ok, but if I just do an "echo", the result is
`'gunzip -dc file.gz | tail +5c'BBB`
and I need the actual result of the gunzip and tails commands.

Comment: @zedascouves did you try it? Notice that I used a couple of ``, not ''. I don't have access to a hp-ux machine, but it works as expected on both linux and osx.